# Unable to get Laravel ECHO to transmit events to the vue js front end (NON SPA)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-echo

I've been encountering a significant challenge that I've been unable to resolve. I'm currently developing a non-single-page application (SPA) where I'm incorporating Vue components within Blade files. The issue appears to be originating from Vue.js, despite correctly sending events via WebSockets. I've thoroughly examined my Vue console, and no errors are being reported.

Here's a glimpse of my Vue front-end code.

```
    created() {
        window.Echo.private(`user.${this.userId}`)
            .listen('.SmartLight', (event) => {
                console.log(event.id);  //nothing received
                alert(event.id);  //nothing received

            });
}
```

My event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SmartLight implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public int $id;
    public array $userIds;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param array $userIds
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(int $id, array $userIds)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->userIds = $userIds;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        // Create private channels for each user ID in the array
        $channels = [];

        foreach ($this->userIds as $userId) {
            $channels[] = new PrivateChannel("user.{$userId}");
        }
        return $channels;
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id
        ];
    }
}
```

Telescope is detecting the event going out as:

```
{
"id": 135,
"userIds": [
376
]
}
```

I am also seeing the event going out on the websockets console as:

```
Channel: private-user.376, Event: App\Events\SmartLight
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Bootstrap.js:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wssHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: true,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted: true
});
```

I have established a stable WebSocket connection, but I'm not receiving any events on my frontend. Any insights into why I'm not getting any data, please?